# While importing pandas in python version 3.10, getting errors related to incompatible architecture

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have python 3.9 and 3.10 versions installed on my Mac.I am currently using only V3.10 for programming. In VSCode and Jupiter notebook, if I try importing pandas I am not getting any errors and import works fine. But when I try the importing the same in Atom, I get the below error:

```
python3.10
Python 3.10.1 (v3.10.1:2cd268a3a9, Dec  6 2021, 14:28:59) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for

many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.10 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.22.1"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.
Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_uma
th.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core
/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib
/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

The command file ${which python} yields the foll. output:

```
file $(which python)
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executa
ble arm64e]
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):      Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python (for architecture arm64e):      Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

I have tried multiple ways of resolving it installing/uninstalling few times but the error keeps coming.